# Getting this exception org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: https protocol is not supported

Tags: java, http, https, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to make an http POST call to a url with some parameters ,headers and a json input in java

Below is the method i use for making the call and exception gets thrown at this line
'CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);'

```
    public String postJsonWithHttpParams(String url) throws URISyntaxException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    //add the http parameters you wish to pass
    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api-version", "2.0"));

    //Build the server URI together with the parameters you wish to pass
    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
    uriBuilder.addParameters(postParameters);

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());
    postRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    //this is your JSON string you are sending as a request
    String yourJsonString = getAuthTokenJsonString ();

    //pass the json string request in the entity
    HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(yourJsonString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    postRequest.setEntity(entity);

    //create a socketfactory in order to use an http connection manager
    PlainConnectionSocketFactory plainSocketFactory = PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> connSocketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", plainSocketFactory)
            .build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(connSocketFactoryRegistry);

    connManager.setMaxTotal(20);
    connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

    
    // Build the http client.
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connManager)
         //   .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig)
            .build();

    System.out.println(postRequest);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);

    //Read the response
    String responseString = "";

    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    String message = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

    HttpEntity responseHttpEntity = response.getEntity();

    InputStream content = responseHttpEntity.getContent();

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;

    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        responseString += line;
    }

    //release all resources held by the responseHttpEntity
    EntityUtils.consume(responseHttpEntity);

    //close the stream
    response.close();

    // Close the connection manager.
    connManager.close();

    return responseString;
}
```

and below is the exception i'm getting

```
    org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: https protocol is not supported
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:109)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
```

is there a way i can make http call to https sites ? i can see the response coming back when i try in postman , so there is no need of any kind of certificates.

Comment: You have a `PlainConnectionSocketFactory ` and you register only `http` as known protocol. When you now try to open an https URL this will fail of course because you have restricted it to http only.

Comment: Thanks robert.. i tried changing that to https .. and now i'm getting this exception.      java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)

Comment: A PlainSocketFactory can only handle http traffic, if you want https you need an SSLSocketFactory. You should better check the official examples instead of using defect code you don't understand: https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientConfiguration.java#L145

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your request must be encrypted in order to be interpreted by the server. But HTTPS is not supported by the API, as the error shows.

Comment: I am able to make the request and get a response successfully via postman.. is there a way i can make call to https urls ?